# GET request works sometimes in Postman, but fails with Axios

Tags: javascript, axios, postman

I try to make a get request using Postman which it works there with 200 status, after a while (15 to 20 mins) it fails with 403 status (forbidden), when I restart postman it works!!
Using Axios it never works.. I get 403 status (forbidden), someone has any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like csrf token validation. Pls check with the token generation and expiration time.